# How to handle SQL exceptions in Spring batch JDBC batch write

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have spring batch which reads from ActiveMQ Artemis and write to Oracle database. Now I want to implement a mechanism to cater if any SQLException occured in JDBC batch write like following,

`org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL`

I tried with `SkipPolicy` and `CompositeStepExecutionListener` but it seems methods not get called on error. My target is to write the error prone message to a error queue or logs. Is there a way I can do it without extending `JdbcBatchItemWriter`. Also I want to know your opinion on whether my error handing is efficient?

Answer (score 1):

> My target is to write the error prone message to a error queue or logs

[`ItemWriteListener#onWriteError`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ItemWriteListener.html#onWriteError-java.lang.Exception-java.util.List-) should be called on write failures. It gives you access to the items of the failed chunk as well as the exception that caused the failure. You can implement this listener and send failed items to your error queue or log them as needed.